# Google+ Auto Enhance photo album

Tags: google-plus, photos

Google+ recently released a feature that allows me to [auto enhance](http://www.engadget.com/2013/05/15/google-highlights-auto-enhance-photo-editing/) my photos.

However I seem to have to auto enhance each photo individually, which is pretty useless when I've got hundreds of photos. Is there any way I can auto enhance a whole album at once?

Comment: FYI google+ will automatically auto-enhance *new* photos, but i have lots of old ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im guessing you found the answer by now but I will explain anyway by quoting Google's Denise Ho

> In the weeks and months ahead, we'll also be enhancing and awesome'ing the photos you've already uploaded to Google+ -- it just takes a while to process billions and billions of pictures :-)

In the meantime you can either apply Auto Enhance to existing photos one at a time, or upload new pictures to Google+ to have them enhanced automatically."

Comment: Ah, I had not found the answer, so thank you for this. I guess I'll have to be patient then.